# WPF MVVM Observable Collection doesn't update GUI correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I am trying to create an application in which you can select a dish and it is automatically added to your order.

So I made this XAML code with a `ListView` which contains the dishes in your order. It is supposed to update automatically whenever a dish is added (with a `RelayCommand`).

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewn:ViewModelOrder/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<ListView x:Name="CommandListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Order}" >
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name_Dish}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price_Dish}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Below you can see the Order `ObservableCollection` bound to the `ListView`

```
public class ViewModelOrder : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Dish> _Order;    
    public ObservableCollection<Dish> Order
    {
        get { return _Order; }
        set
        {
            _Order = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Order");
        }
    }
}
```

What is really strange is that the business logic is working as intended (the order `ObservableCollection` is filled with the dishes), however these changes don't show up on the `ListView`.

What is even stranger, is that when the application is running and I add a dot at the end of the Binding so it looks like this: `ItemsSource="{Binding Order.}"`, the UI is updated exactly as intended (it shows all the dishes previously added and updates whenever I add another one). So I'm not really sure what is causing this problem.

Have you got any idea what could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

It appears that there is a problem with a binding in my XAML. Indeed, the output window shows the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'AddDishToOrder' property not found on 'object' ''Dish_801880DFD6EB7B0C17C1467B62FCB73FB779084FCF737D81239B8934238C3474' (HashCode=45081147)'. BindingExpression:Path=AddDishToOrder; DataItem='Dish_801880DFD6EB7B0C17C1467B62FCB73FB779084FCF737D81239B8934238C3474' (HashCode=45081147); target element is 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

This error is thrown on this button generated for all the dishes:

```
<ItemsControl Name="DishesItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Dishes}">
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Command="{Binding AddDishToOrder}">
            <Button.DataContext>
                <viewn:ViewModelOrder/>
            </Button.DataContext>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The binding is calling this method:

```
private RelayCommand _addDishToOrder;
public RelayCommand AddDishToOrder
{
    get
    {
        if (_addDishToOrder == null)
        {
            //The DoAddDish method simply add the dish to the ObservableCollection
            _addDishToOrder = new RelayCommand<object>(DoAddDish);
        }
        return _addDishToOrder;
    }
    set { _addDishToOrder = value; }
}
```

If I understand correctly, the error comes from the buttons used to add dishes to the order. But I can't exactly understand what's wrong with them since the method is called correctly when I debug.

Comment: Can you show us how you assign `DataContext` to your `Window` `Control` or whatever you are using? This seems like `Binding` issue so we need a full visual tree here or at least a sample that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I edited my post to add the DataContext.

Comment: Is the ListView immediate child of the UserControl? Or is there a Grid on top of it? And lastly is this used as a `DataTemplate` anywhere?

Comment: `What is really strange is that the business logic is working as intended (the order ObservableCollection is filled with the dishes), however these changes don't show up on the ListView.` You mean when you debug, the `ObservableCollection` is filled with values, but the `UI` is not updating, right? Can you add a code explaining how are you assigning value to the `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: Try changing the `DisplayMemberBinding` to `DisplayMemberPath` on `GridViewColumn`. This should solve the issue.

Comment: @XAMlMAX No, the `ListView` is in a `Grid`. I'm using `DataTemplate` above my `ListView` but they are not related at all.
I can't add `DisplayMemberPath` in my `GridViewColumn`, I can only see `DisplayMemberBinding` with the autocompletion.

Comment: @Mahmoud I have a button bound to a method which then add the correpsonding dish to the `ObservableCollection` like so `Order.Add(dish);`

Comment: I deleted my answer. What I have found is that you should put `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name_Dish}"`. Sorry for posting wrong info.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Even if the `Binding Path` in the template was wrong, he should be able to see an empty item in the `GridView` I suppose, don't you think so?

Comment: @XAMlMAX This still won't work unfortunately, it has the same beahviour as before.

Comment: Nope @Mahmoud . This `ItemsSource` Binding is causing issue here. It is not resolved properly. BTW @Antoine Delia you wouldn't get any error:40 in your Output Window?

Comment: @AntoineDelia I'm concerned about the `Thread` who `Instantiate` and `Add` values to your `ObservableCollection`. If `XAMIMAX` solution doesn't work for you. Make sure that the `UI Thread` has instantiated the `ObservableCollection` and that it's the one who is updating the `ObservableCollection`. I've a similar problem before , and it turns out to be a `Thread` issue

Comment: Yes, as @XAMlMAX mentioned, check your output `Window` for binding error. To eliminate the `Binding` Sources/Paths issue.

Comment: Not sure, but one thing is for sure is that collection properties should be read only. The whole reason for ObservableCollections is that they notify on collection change.  Also, tools like Snoop are great for examining your bindings at runtime.

Comment: Indeed @XAMlMAX, I have an error 40 on the binding supposed to call the method adding the dish to the order. However, when I debug it, the program goes into it well and add my dishes to the order.

Comment: Can you update your post and paste the error details?

Comment: @XAMlMAX I updated the post with the errors I'm getting.

Comment: Please add a [mcve], saying you have binding error without showing the binding in question is not useful.

Comment: This is all messed up mate. You need to provide us with the **FULL CODE** that you are using. **NEVER** assign data context in the `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @XAMIMAX pointed it out, I had a `DataContext` inside my `Button` which was completely wrong. So, I changed the code for my button to something like this and now it totally works:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddDishToOrder}" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
```

Comment: You are still assigning `DataContext` inside of the `DataTemplate` replace your code with this: `Command="{Binding DataContext.AddDishToOrder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "path" keyword in your binding like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name_Dish}"/>
```

Comment: That will have no effect. `Path` is inferred when no property is specified.

Comment: `Binding` has [this constructor overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578(v=vs.110).aspx) which accept `string` path. When specifying `Path` property, then parameterless constructor is used. Both methods should achieve same result.

Answer (score -4):

If I correct understand your problem, you should not wrap _Order by the property, you should simply use:

```
public class ViewModelOrder : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{   
    public ObservableCollection<Dish> Order{get;set;}
}
```